# Android Studio ignores GRADLE_USER_HOME?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have Windows environment variables assigned

```
GRADLE_HOME=C:\Tools\gradle
GRADLE_OPTS=-Dgradle.user.home=C:/Tools/gradle
GRADLE_USER_HOME=c:\Tools\gradle
```

When running `gradlew build` from command line, all project dependencies are loaded to `C:\Tools\gradle`.

But if I make build from Android Studio, gradle uses `C:\Users\MyUserName\.gradle` directory.

AS bug?

Comment: I found this too. Did you find a solution for this?